# Linking javascript files in HTML causing slider to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 sliders on my web page but it seems when i link all the js into the html page only the one slider will work and the other will not show up. I have narrowed it down to all the new js files i import for the new slider make the old slider not show up.

the old slider js links are below

```
    <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

<!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
```

new slider js links

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pngFix/jquery.pngFix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mopSlider/mopSlider-2.4.js"></script>

<script src="js/salesSlider.js"></script>
```

I believe it's something todo with the files clashing somehow, does anyone know what is really going on here.

Note to get the old slider to show up every single new js link has to be removed.

If you need any more code just ask and i can provide.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the same version of jQuery for both sliders?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: No if i use an newer version my new slider disappears. Errors that appear: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.browser` has been removed since jQuery 1.9.  One of the sliders that you have requires it, so you have a couple of options.

1. See if you can use jQuery 1.8 (or less) for *both* sliders.
2. [Use a `jQuery.browser` shim](https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.browser.js)
3. Include both versions of jQuery, but use [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) -- this probably won't work since both sliders most likely want to use the `jQuery` variable.

Comment: How do i go about option 2 ?

Comment: @BumblebeeStudio just include the linked file with `<script>` tags *after* you have included jQuery (but before anything else).  Just the one jQuery -- the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.browser` has been removed from 1.9. Instead, you can use `navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)` to check if the browser type.